# How Can I store RecylerView With Use SQliteOpenHelper

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have recyclerview on my project . and It can work successfuly . I want store my recyclerview with use SQliteOpenHelper but ıf you know another basic storing way then write please I can another storeing way.  Can you be fast It's important .

**MainActivity.java**

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomSheetDialogx.BottomSheetListener {
        
        Button listeo;
       
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        List<String> Lists = new ArrayList<>();
        CustomAdapter adapter;
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_todolist);
            recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewx);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
            adapter=new CustomAdapter(Lists);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            
            
        }
       
        @Override
        public void onButtonClick(String text) {
            Lists.add(text);
            adapter.notifyItemInserted(Lists.size()-1);
    
        }
    }
```

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.Holder> {
    List<String> Lists;
    public CustomAdapter(List<String>itemxx){
        this.Lists = itemxx;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CustomAdapter.Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row_item,parent,false);
        Holder holder = new Holder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomAdapter.Holder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(Lists.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return Lists.size();
    }

    public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        public Holder(View view) {
            super(view);
            textView=view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't save recyclerview, instead you should store recyclerview data based on it's model class in sqlite.

Comment: ok how can ı store ReyclerView thx for warning

Comment: I did edit my quastion

Comment: follow instructions https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite, however i suggest using room database

Answer (score 0):

Use Room library instead of SQliteOpenHelper.